# Using Javascript to provide specific form results

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, forms

I am rebuilding a very old site I created, related to the history of the Holocaust.  I have a form for a gallery to upload an image.  There are two initial things it needs to know.

1. Category
2. Album

I select the category first:

```
@foreach ($gallery_categories as $gallery_category)
    <div>
        <label class="capitalize">{{ $gallery_category->name }}</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gallery_category_id" value="{{ $gallery_category->id }}">
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Just for the visuals it looks like this.

[image]

Then comes the part I am having the issue with.  You now need to pick the album that you want the image to be associated with.  I can easily pull all the albums in but I only want the ones that are linked to the category.

The code to display the albums is basically the same as shown above, just change $categories to $albums.

What I want to do is click on one of the categories and it will then only display the albums associated with that category.

I may be going down the wrong route with this.  I am not experienced with Javascript but have used a couple of basic listeners on my menus to show/hide them.

My thought process was to use Javascript:

1. Create listener for when I click on one of the categories.
2. On clicking a category it (somehow) grabs the id which I can then pass to a new foreach loop that will display the associated albums on the page.

Does any of that make sense?  Apologies, old guy trying to learn new things.

Comment: To make it easier for you, you could just return HTML from an API route. Have you considered that?

Comment: No, hadn't considered that as an option, thanks will look at that method.

Comment: Ok, please get back to me here if you have questions.